SSRS failed upgrade from 2014 to 2016
I upgraded our SSRS from 2014 to 2016, and also applied SP3 and KB5029187.
Following the upgrade, accessing the URL results in the below error. The Reportserver DB instance is still 2014.
I have done the same steps in staging server it worked fine but am getting this error only in production.
Error:
The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '178'. The expected version is '162'.
(rsInvalidReportServerDatabase)
